# Kivy FileChooser doubleclick

Tags: python, kivy

Could somebody post a small working example of a kivy Filechooser with the following simple doubleclick function:  doubleclicking on a file will print out the filename?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of that.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class MyFileChooser(FileChooserListView):

    def on_submit(*args):
        print(args[1][0])


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyLayout,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # filter added. Since windows will throw error on sys files
        self.fclv = MyFileChooser(filters= [lambda folder, filename: not filename.endswith('.sys')])
        self.add_widget(self.fclv)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: which version of Kivy are you using?

Comment: @picibucor v1.9.1. Sry I forgot to print the filename :D I will update

Comment: your code does not work for me. I am using the newest nightly build (2017.02.22)

Comment: @picibucor okey, it should still work tho.. Any errors?

Comment: @picibucor try take the `path='.'` out of `MyFileChooser`. There were some issues around that, at that date.

Comment: pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird.')

Comment: @picibucor I dont know what language that is. But seems to me that the file you doubleclick is used by another process, and that is why you cannot get the data.

Comment: pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', The process cannot be accessed because another process uses it.)

Comment: Sorry, it starts with:       File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 178, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN

Comment: @picibucor https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/filechooser.py#L178 yes so as it says under that error: This error can occurred when a file is already accessed by someone else.

Comment: @picibucor that said, I am on linux, and have tried open a .jpg file for example, and then try to double click in the kivy app, and still works here. I have a windows pc, that I will try this in, in a moment.

Comment: @picibucor yes it works. Navigate to a file, doubleclick, and it will print. Alltho the same error as you mention pops up if I am in the directory where the python file which I run is. So you can ignore that error

Comment: @picibucor actually the problem is sys files in windows. To get rid of it, you can exclude sys files with a filter. I will add the filter in my answer.

Comment: The filter works like a charm, there is no error. But the double-click is not working.

Comment: I've also installed kivy 1.9.2 , maybe it's the problem is in the dev-branch but nothing changed.

Comment: @picibucor weird. I tested it on windows, also newly installed, and it prints the filename. Tho only if it is not a directory. It will only open the directory. But file names print

Answer (score 2):

I think it is simpler than that.

FileChooser has an argument `dirselect`. By default it is False making it single-click. If you change `dirselect` to True, it works as double-click.

For example, in kivy language

```
BoxLayout:
    FileChooserIconView:
        size_hint: (0.3, 0.4)
        dirselect: True
```

For example, in python language

```
FileChooserListView(size_hint_x=0.3, size_hint_y=0.4, dirselect=True)
```

Hope it helps somebody