# How do I make FileChooser update it's path or selection [Kivy]?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, filechooser

I'm very new to Kivy and through a lot of trial and error have gotten a pretty decent working app.

What I can't for the life of me figure out is how to get the FileChooser to update its path based on what I've selected (directory or otherwise).

`.selection` always returns and empty list and `.path` always returns the starting directory even after I have moved around. I'm missing some event somewhere and have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and was hoping someone here could help.

I thought `.selection` and `.path` would update as I navigated but they seem stuck on their first/default values. I made the `testbutton` just to see if I could get path or selection to print out/update.

This all gets triggered once they hit another button

```
def testbutton(self,test,iconview,*args):
    print(test,iconview.path)

filepop=Popup(title='SaveFile')
FileChooserLayout=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
ButtonArea=BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal',spacing=50,size_hint=(.5,.5),pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5})    
listview=FileChooserListView(path='somepath',dirselect=True)
test=listview.path
testbutton=Button(text='test',on_press=partial(self.testbutton, test,iconview))
ButtonArea.add_widget(testbutton)
FileChooserLayout.add_widget(ButtonArea)
filepop.add_widget(FileChooserLayout)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

In *FileChooserListView*, use `on_selection` event and pass `*args` to the method. Please refer to the example for details.

## snippets

```
        FileChooserListView:
            on_selection: 
                app.root.selected_file(*args)
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.10.0

<SaveFile>:
    title: 'Save File'

    # FileChooserLayout
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        # ButtonArea
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            spacing: 50
            size_hint: (.5,.5)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

            FileChooserListView:
                on_selection: 
                    app.root.selected_file(*args)

<RootWidget>:

''')


class SaveFile(Popup):
    pass


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        filepop = SaveFile()
        filepop.open()

    def selected_file(self, *args):
        print("*args=", args)
        for arg in args:
            print("arg=", arg)


class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - *args displayed]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was trying to do this w/o using .kv files. I hit another wall earlier on making buttons iteratively and found it easier (for me) to do it in straight python. I've done a pretty piss poor job creating separate classes for different widgets. Currently almost the entire app is under 1 class...

So when I try to use your method which would be something like self.on_selection it just refers to the class which makes sense. I can't make it refer to itself because that's the same line I'm calling the on_selection.

Answer (score 0):

I found success with the event on_submit

https://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/uix/filechooser.html

I had to make each type of FileChooser in my program it's own class and give it the on_submit function then I can get a response of the address to print.

```
class FileChooserI(FileChooserIconView):
    def on_submit(*args):
        print(args[1][0])
```

This post really helped: [Kivy FileChooser doubleclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393319/kivy-filechooser-doubleclick#42398038)

Comment: i'm new to kivy too, but you can 'bind' to the on_submit event, or pass `on_submit = funcname` to the constructor, and only use 1 class